# Cocos2D game ABC123 cannot run on iPad

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2D and I'm now trying ABC123 (downloaded from internet, created by kwigbo)
I wonder why it works all fine by the simulator, but while i'm using my iPad to test it.... problem comes up.. I tried for 2weeks but still cannot solve it... hope anyone can teach me?? Thanks a lot....

Originally the bubble will appear AFTER player memorized the word's locations, but when using iPad to run it... the bubble appear soon after started, player cannot remember the word locations for playing the game at all...

I've tried to change the delay part from delayTime = 1.5 to 4;:

@GameLayer.m

```
float delayTime = 4.0;
if(dataManager.currentlevel > 10) delayTime = 2.5;

[self runAction:[Sequence actions:[DelayTime actionWithDuration:delayTime], [CallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(showBubbles)], nil]];
```

It delay in simulator but didn't change in iPad....

Is there any relationship with OrbSprite.m?

@OrbSprite.m's init:

```
Label *l = [[Label alloc] initWithString:@"" dimensions:CGSizeMake(50, 50) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Arial Rounded MT Bold" fontSize:45];
self.label = l;
[l release];

//[self initWithFile:@"bubble1.png"];
Animation *bub = [Animation animationWithName:@"bubble" delay:1.0f images:@"bubble1.png", @"bubble2.png", nil];
self.bubble = bub;
[bub release];

[self addAnimation:bubble];
```

Or should I do anything on this line?

```
- (void) showBubble
{
    isBubble = YES;

    [self setDisplayFrame:@"bubble" index:1];
    self.scale = .1;
    [self runAction:[Sequence actions: [ScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1 scale:0.1], [ScaleTo actionWithDuration:.1 scale:1], nil]];
    [self removeChild:label cleanup:YES];
}
```

Comment: Are you using some form of Cocos2D I haven't seen? I've never seen `ScaleTo`, only `CCScaleTo`

Comment: I just downloaded from internet.... I think the version is Cocos2D v0.7.1...

Comment: I downloaded from here:
http://iphonesourcecodeshop.com/?p=39

Comment: Cocos2D has had many many versions since then. I think we're up to 2.0.x. You might want to find a more up to date tutorial.

Comment: yes, this is a really old cocos2d version dating back to 2009 I think